# Librosa writing an audio time series [y] as float64 even when specified to write as float32

Tags: python, scipy, librosa

Librosa is writing an audio file with `y` as `ndtype=float64` even though I hand it as a `float32`. I am using version `0.7.2`. Am I doing something wrong? Here is basically what I'm doing:

```
y, sr = librosa.load("audio_file", mono=False, sr=None, dtype='float32')
print(y.dtype) # float32
librosa.output.write_wav("output_audio_path", y, sr)
y, sr = librosa.load("output_audio_path", mono=False, sr=None, dtype=None)
print(y.dtype) #float64
```

Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

librosa always returns float64, regardless of the underlying format of a WAV file.

If you want more control over the details in audio I/O, use [pysoundfile](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) directly. Or even the [wave](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html) module in Python standard library.